# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

Tags: java, class, jboss, wildfly-8

I am moving jboss-4.0.4.GA to wildfly-8.1.0.Final. while deploying my EAR I'm getting following error:

> 2014-07-10 17:09:44,900 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)
>   javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate
>   InitialContextFactory
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader
>   ModuleClassLoader for Module
>   "deployment.wildfly.ear.wildfly-war.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module
>   "deployment.wildfly.ear.wildfly-war.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]]

My code:

```
Properties appProp = new Properties();
appProp.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CGProperties.initial_context_factory);
appProp.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, CGProperties.provider_url);
appProp.put("java.naming.rmi.security.manager", "yes");
appProp.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming");
appProp.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context","true");
context = new InitialContext(appProp);
//context = new InitialContext();

if(serverName.equalsIgnoreCase("JBOSS")) {
    ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) context.lookup(CGProperties.dsName);
    reportDS=(javax.sql.DataSource) context.lookup(CGProperties.reportdsName);
}
```

Please Help me to solve this error.

Comment: Can you post list of jars you have added in your project.
Check if jboss-client jar is added or not. it is required.

Comment: Thax for your reply Neeraj :) i having jboss-client.jar in wildfly-8.1.0.Final\bin\client. how can i  add this jar global y to my application

Answer (score 1):

Either the jboss-client.jar needs to be added or corresponding WildFly module be included.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417564/whats-the-best-way-to-use-the-jboss-client-jar-in-a-wildfly-10-application/50329636#50329636) the following config in the *standalone-full.xml* does the trick:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0"><!-- ee:2.0  in WildFly 8 -->
                <global-modules>
                    <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming"/>
                </global-modules>
...
```

which allows to lookup for a remote connection on another WildFly server.